# About "except+verb"

Tags: phrase-usage, infinitive-vs-gerund

From *George Orwell* *SHOOTING AN ELEPHANT*:

> The young Buddhist priests were the worst of all. There were several thousands of them in the town and none of them seemed to have anything to do **except stand** on street corners and jeer at Europeans.

It uses *except stand*, not *standing*, I am bad at grammar sometimes but using *except Ving* here is more comfortable to me, is it acceptable to use *Ving* after *except*? If so what's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the ordinary use.

Parse *stand* and *jeer* as infinitives, in strict parallel with the infinitive *do*.

```
 [not] anything to        do 
                   except stand ... and jeer
```

You may also write this with a marked infinitive:

```
 [not] anything        to do 
                except to stand ... and jeer
```

But this is not very common; ordinarily we ellipt the second *to* marker, allowing the *to* marker on *do* to flow over onto *stand ... and jeer*.

Your version, with *standing ... and jeering* would set these gerunds in parallel with *anything*. It's formally acceptable, but non-idiomatic.

Another way of expressing this would be

```
 None of them does anything but stand ... and jeer
```

In this case *stand ... and jeer* is a conjunct complement to the auxiliary *does*.

Comment: In your last example, *does* is an auxiliary verb? It takes an object (anything).

Comment: @KinzleB In English we express a "pro-verb" (analogous to a "pro-noun") with *do* + nominal, so despite appearances, *anything* is neither a pronoun nor an object but a proverb and a non-finite complement!

Comment: So *does* here is an intransitive, and *anything but stand ... and jeer* is a complement??

Comment: @KinzleB That's how I'd parse it, because that makes sense out of the construction; but there's plenty of room for argument.

Comment: That's new to me; I need to study more of the modern linguistics. I'm becoming more and more interested in sentence parsing. Thank you!

Comment: I found a line [here](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=8&keyword=antiquities): _What did I ever do to you except deliver the South?_ This sentence seems to have a different structure than that of the one OP asked about. I wonder if **deliver** here is a bare infinitive or finite verb. It seems verbs can follow _except_ even without the _to_ marker.

Comment: @EddieKal It's a bare infinitive; it takes that form because it is implicitly the complement of *did*. Compare "What did I do? Deliver the South!"